# C/C++: How does this inline if get parsed?

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

Consider this code:

```
int main()
{
    cout << true ? "Yes" : "No";
    return 0;
}
```

Its output will be `1` , not `Yes` or `No`. Why is it that `true` is sent to the output stream instead of the `Yes` or `No` strings? How does the rest of the inline if get parsed?

Comment: See http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence

Comment: operators precedence - use parenthesis

Comment: next question (will probably be closed if i asked it): why does "cout << true;" print "1". what's with this design decision?

Comment: @Agnel Kurian: I guess it has to do with the fact that storing `1` or `0` is the most simple/efficient way of representing a boolean value in a text file. Moreover it is language agnostic.

Comment: Its not called an "inline if," it's called the "conditional operator."  Sometimes it's referred to as the "ternary operator" because it's the only operator in C++ that takes 3 parameters.

Comment: @John Dibling Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has to do with order of operations.  It's the same as:

```
  (cout << true) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

`cout << true` returns an `ostream&`, which must have a conversion to bool or an equivalent.  The result of `?:` is thrown away.

If this seems odd (why this precedence?), just remember that ostream's `operator<<` is an overload introduced in C++ code, which doesn't allow precedence changing.  The precedence of `<<` is designed for what makes sense for bit-shifting.  Its use as a streaming operator came much later.

Edit: Probably converting to `(void*)` using this:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/

Comment: Aha, thank you! Exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for. :)

Comment: Almost always a good idea to put ternary operators in parenthesis, it generally helps readability: `cout << (true ? "Yes" : "No");`

Comment: @GrahamS: not to mention that more parens help my code reviewer when I meant `x == y ? foo() : bar();` but typed `x = y ? foo() : bar();`. If I'd typed `(x = y) ? foo() : bar();`, that looks far more suspect before I even know what any of the variables and functions mean. Admittedly, that's not a very realistic error, you'd be unlucky if that compiled and even vaguely looked like working, but it's another case where the ternary operator benefits from some help with readability.

Comment: I always use parentheses. I just noticed this little bit of unexpected behavior and I wanted to know what caused it.